# jQuery function is not working in PHP once the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, refresh, show-hide

I want to "Hide" the table during the starting of page, which is working using `$(document).ready(function(){$("#result").hide();});`
But I also want to "show" the table once the submit button is clicked, which is not working.

This is the PHP file, as I have to add more PHP code afterwards. Same result if I change this to HTML thou.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
       <head>
              <title>  Show Specific </title>
              <meta charset = "utf-8">
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
              <script
                     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
                     integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
                     crossorigin="anonymous">
              </script>

              <script>
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#result").hide();
                     });
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#button").click(function(){
                                   $("#result").show();//result
                            });
                     });
              </script>
       </head>
       <body>   
    
            <hr>
              
            <div id="appointment">
                <form>
                    Test ID: <input type="text" name="testID" /> <br><br>
                    First Name : <input type="text" name="First_Name" /> <br><br>
                    Last Name : <input type="text" name="Last_Name" /> <br><br>
                    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" ><br><br>
                </form>
            </div>
                
            <div id="result">
                <table>
                    <tr> 
                    <th>Test ID</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th>First Name </th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                        
            <hr>

            <div id="footer">
                <footer>   Copyright &copy; ALL RIGHTS ARE RESERVED. </footer>
            </div>

       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your submit is doing a page navigation, in this case the page gets reloaded. CSS changes do not persist through page navigations. If you want some change to persist you would have to save some kind of state information to something like `localStorage` and redo that change at page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully, the `id` of your input button is `submit` not `button` as you have written on your jQuery event handler.

Change your script to this one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#result").hide();
     $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("#result").show();//result
     });
});
</script>
```

**Also:** it is not necessary for you to have two `$(document).ready()` methods. Just implement one, and then add your function inside.